# Call json sprite file in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, html5-canvas, sprite-sheet

I have a json file that was generated from a program to render images (converted from flash) the file looks like this:

```
{
"framerate":24,
 "images":[
"flash_0.png",
"flash_1.png",
"flash_2.png",
"flash_3.png",
"flash_4.png",
"flash_5.png",
"flash_6.png",
// ................ 
"frames":[
[0, 0, 1024, 512, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 512, 1024, 512, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1024, 1024, 512, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1536, 1024, 512, 0, 0, 0],
// ...................
```

And the images are in the same folder. My question is: how do I render it in an html file with js?

Comment: Like you realized already, you're going to have to re-implement the functionality of the Flash part in JavaScript. If you show us some work you did, we'll be happy to help you along with a single problem you're stuck with.

Comment: Where/how do I start. Links to examples to similar problem would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you have never used (vanilla) JavaScript before to build anything, this is the wrong place for such a broad task. Use one of the approximately half a trillion tutorials or bootcamps online, or read up on JSON usage in JavaScript, which is rather trivial. When you find yourself stuck on a **single** problem, come back and ask. You have already participated under the jQuery tag, so you should already possess the knowledge to build a first draft on your own.

Comment: I thought this is going to be a simple import. I am new to json but I have only one flash that I am trying to convert to html5 canvas and have used Zoe to convert the flash and that was the output. I will search for simple solution if possible. Any other ideas